# centos 7.3 docker-engine conflicts with docker-common-2

Tags: docker, installation, centos, yum

After following the official installation document below
https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/centos/

I still end up with failure with docker-common-2 transaction conflict

> Transaction check error:
>     file /usr/bin/docker from install of docker-engine-1.13.0-1.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package docker-common-2:1.10.3-59.el7.centos.x86_64

I tried `yum remove docker-common-2` immediately but apparently there is no such package found so I `yum clean all` but the failure is still there.
I had encountered that selinux conflict before and I did remove conflict the package docker-selinux if it is the case.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 13):

OK I managed to solve it by myself.
I searched for `docker-common` instead of `docker-common-2` and I found that conflict package. It should be installed from centos yum repos so just `yum remove -y docker-common` to remove it before you install `docker-engine`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

step 1: `sudo yum erase docker`

step 2: `sudo yum clean all`

and then, Install the required packages,

step 3: `sudo yum install docker-common-2`

Answer (score 0):

After remove docker its good to run following

```
sudo yum autoremove
```

Remove packages that has not dependencies and can be removed from machine.
"yum autoremove" tries to remove any packages that waren’t installed explicitly by the user and which aren’t required.

Answer (score 0):

Using the flowing command solve the problem, actually it is easier.

```
curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh
```

Answer (score 0):

`yum remove -y docker-ce-cli` is helped for me